# Is there a linear-time solution to the minimum window substring problem, provided the characters in the substring must be in order?

Tags: time-complexity, substrings

Suppose there are two strings, $S$ and $T$, and we want to find the length $l$ of the shortest substring of $S$ which contains all the characters in $T$, *in order*. (Assume the length of $T$ is bounded, so it doesn't need to be considered for determining time complexity.)

Here are some examples:

- $S$ = "abcabc", $T$ = "abc", $l = 3$, "[**abc**]abc".
- $S$ = "abcabc", $T$ = "acb", $l = 5$, "[**a**b**c**a**b**]c".
- $S$ = "ben thinks bananas are the best", $T$ = "bans", $l=7$, "ben thinks [**ban**ana**s**] are the best"

I found a solution to this using recursion which I believe is $O(n^2)$.

```python
def ordered_moving_window(S, T, include_prefix=False):
    # Recursion base case
    if len(T) == 0:
        return 0

    shortest_length = float("inf")

    for i in range(len(S)):
        if S[i] == T[0]:
            # Recursively find all the other chars in the string
            length = ordered_moving_window(S[i+1:], T[1:], include_prefix=True) + 1

            # If this is being called recursively, then we need to include
            # all the characters before the first character we found
            # in our length calculation
            if include_prefix:
                length += i
    
            shortest_length = min(length, shortest_length)

    return shortest_length

print(ordered_moving_window("abcabc", "abc")) # 3
print(ordered_moving_window("abcabc", "acb")) # 5
print(ordered_moving_window("ben thinks bananas are the best", "bans")) # 7
```

I believe the worst case for this particular solution is something like $S$ = "aaaaaaaab", $T$ = "ab", where the solution would need to traverse down the list (which is $O(n)$) for each "a" in $S$ (of which there are $n$), leading to a total time complexity of $O(n^2)$.

A few years ago, my professor assigned me a version of this problem, and I submitted this $O(n^2)$ solution. In my solution writeup, I also mentioned that I didn't believe an $O(n)$ solution was possible. My justification was similar to:

> Consider a hypothetical $O(n)$ algorithm where $T$ = "abc". For $S$ = "ababc", the algorithm would need to ignore the first "ab", identify the solution "ab[**abc**]", and return $l = 3$. However, for $S$ = "abac", the algorithm would need to consider the first "ab" to identify the solution "[**ab**a**c**]" and return $l = 4$. Since the algorithm cannot look ahead to figure out whether it should consider or ignore a certain character, it cannot make this decision, and therefore such an algorithm cannot exist.

However, my professor disagreed with me, stating that an $O(n)$ solution to this problem is possible.

Since then, I've learned of the non-ordered minimum window substring problem, which is similar to the problem I listed earlier, but without the requirement that the characters be in order:

- $S$ = "abcabc", $T$ = "acb", $l=3$, "[**abc**]abc"
- $S$ = "ben thinks bananas are the best", $T$ = "bans", $l = 5$, "ben think[**s** **ban**]anas are the best"

This can be solved in $O(n)$ time complexity by keeping pointers to the start and end of the window, using a map to keep track of the characters in the window, advancing the end pointer when the sequence is not valid, and advancing the start pointer when the sequence is valid:

```python
def moving_window_substring(S, T):
    # Build a table of the count of each character in T
    # (i.e., the chars we need our window to have)
    needed_chars = {}
    for char in T:
        if char in needed_chars:
            needed_chars[char] += 1
        else:
            needed_chars[char] = 1

    # Set up the window
    start = 0
    end = 0
    shortest_length = float("inf")
    needed_chars_count = len(T)

    # Grow the window until we have all the chars we need
    while end < len(S):
        end_char = S[end]

        if end_char in needed_chars:
            # If we needed this character, decrement the number of chars we need
            needed_chars[end_char] -= 1
            if needed_chars[end_char] >= 0:
                needed_chars_count -= 1

        if needed_chars_count == 0:
            # The window is valid, we have all the chars we need
            # Start shortening the window until it is no longer valid
            while True:
                start_char = S[start]

                if start_char in needed_chars:
                    if needed_chars[start_char] < 0:
                        needed_chars[start_char] += 1
                    else:
                        # We need this character, break out of the loop
                        break

                start += 1

            shortest_length = min(shortest_length, end - start + 1)

        end += 1

    return shortest_length            

print(moving_window_substring("abcabc", "abc")) # 3
print(moving_window_substring("abcabc", "acb")) # 3
print(moving_window_substring("ben thinks bananas are the best", "bans")) # 5
print(moving_window_substring("ben thinks bananas are the bans", "bans")) # 4
```

Is there a similar $O(n)$-time-complexity solution to the *ordered* version of the problem?

Comment: I just realised you restrict T to constant length, so any algorithm that takes $O(|S||T|)$ time would work. The standard Needleman-Wunsch global alignment algorithm, which has this time complexity, could be easily modified to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if the length of `T` can be considered as a constant.

---

Here is an efficient algorithm.

```python
def shortest_super_subsequence(S, T):
    if len(T) == 0: return 0
    shortest_length = float("inf")

    indices = [-1] * len(T)
    while True:
        for i in range(0, len(T)):
            if i == 0:
                indices[0] = S.find(T[0], indices[0] + 1)
            else:
                indices[i] = S.find(T[i], max(indices[i - 1] + 1, indices[i]))
            if indices[i] == -1:
                return shortest_length
        shortest_length = min(shortest_length,
                              indices[-1] - indices[0] + 1)
```

---

The algorithm above uses `indices[i]` to track the position of `T[i]` found in each search of a subsequence that contains `T`. Each time we will move to right by one position to search for `T[0]`. For other character `T[i]`,  we will start search at the later position of its current position and one position later than the current position of `T[i-1]`.

Let `len(S)` be $n$. The algorithm above runs in time $O(n)$ if the length of `T` is considered as a constant. If `len(T)` is denoted by variable $m$, it runs in time $O(nm)$, since all updates on `indices[j]` need $O(n)$ time for each `j`. The worst case happens in situations like `S="abdabdabdabdabdabdabdc"` and `T="abababc"`.

The algorithm can be speed-up by breaking the inner loop if `indices[j]` stays the same. Although significant, this improvement does not change the asymptotic time-complexity.

The algorithm can be thought as sliding a window (of varying size) from index `indices[0]` to `indices[-1]`.

Comment: "if the length of T can be considered as a constant." should have been "if the length of T is bounded by a constant."

Comment: Ah, using `max(indices[i - 1] + 1, indices[i])` instead of just `indices[i - 1] + 1` is what enables the total work done updating each `indices[j]` to be $O(n)$ time -- the leftmost valid position of `T[j]` will never slide left as we move the starting position to the right, so we can safely start searching for it from where we left off last time.